# Creating IDs for middle point of line

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, virtual-layer, unique-id

I have line layer as shown here:
[image]

I created middle point of line by using the below query in virtual layer.

```sql
SELECT ST_StartPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry, 0.5, 1))
FROM "TR_ROAD copy"
```

The problem is it only creates the middle point without creating data (IDs) for middlepoints(nodes).

[image]

Is there are way to create unique ids for each middle point as sample is shown in last image

[image]

Comment: Why not to use the id from the line layer? or you particularly need a new one?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the SQLite function *row_number()* for that, see this example:

```sql
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) rownum,
    name,
    st_startpoint(st_line_substring(geometry, 0.5, 1))
FROM
    "test"
```

with this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to start the row number with 5000 not 1? Should I say RowNum+5000 ?\

Comment: Secondly, the rownum only add integers. what if i want to use ids with integers and strings as shown in image in question?

Comment: `select 'node'||(rowid+4999) as id from ...` It is just SQL.